# dynamic JContainer (JSON.NET) & Iterate over properties at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, json.net

I'm receiving a JSON string in a MVC4/.NET4 WebApi controller action. The action's parameter is `dynamic` because I don't know anything on the receiving end about the JSON object I'm receiving.

```
 public dynamic Post(dynamic myobject)
```

The JSON is automatically parsed and the resulting `dynamic` object is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer`. I can, as expected, evaluate properties at runtime, so if the JSON contained something like myobject.myproperty then I can now take the dynamic object received and call `myobject.myproperty` within the C# code. So far so good.

Now I want to iterate over all properties that were supplied as part of the JSON, including nested properties. However, if I do `myobject.GetType().GetProperties()` it only returns properties of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer` instead of the properties I'm looking for (that were part of the JSON).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a) article might help you, check out what he's doing in the `DeserializeRequest` method.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think this can be a starting point

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{a:1,b:2}");

//JContainer is the base class
var jObj = (JObject)dynObj;

foreach (JToken token in jObj.Children())
{
    if (token is JProperty)
    {
        var prop = token as JProperty;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

this also may help you

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jObj.ToString());
```

Comment: @Alex Then things are getting complicated and you may have to write a recursive function. You should always check JObject,JArray,JProperty etc, Basically you should repeat what `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` does.

Comment: @Alex I guess deserializing to a `Dictionary<string, object>` may help also. See the edit.