# Convert string to object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, object

I have a string in the form of 
`"{value: "some"}"`
(Obtained by serializing object but without quotes on the property name) OR
`"{"value": "some"}"`

I wish to convert it a object (Similar to new `{value = "some"}`)
And not JObject `{"value" = "some"}`

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652983/dynamic-jcontainer-json-net-iterate-over-properties-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) for info on deserializing anonymous types using Json.NET.

```
var definition = new { Name = "" };
string json1 = @"{'Name':'James'}";
var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);

Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name);
// James

string json2 = @"{'Name':'Mike'}";
var customer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json2, definition);

Console.WriteLine(customer2.Name);
// Mike
```

Comment: Thank you but it requires me know the properties of the object (which is unknown and varies)

Comment: @MohitJain you've not specified this requirement in your question