# Create a object of anonymous type from a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net, object, dictionary

Some dictionary, `"key1" = "Value1, "key2" = "Value2", ...`.
I need to create a object

`{
    key1 : "Value1",
    key2 : "Value2", 
   ...
 }`

Comment: SmartFormat.Net library requires you to pass object in the form mentioned above @grant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to object in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027613/convert-string-to-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You might not need to do this. SmartFormat.NET handles dictionaries. `var dict = new Dictionary<String,Object>() { {"Name", "Smart"},{ "Address", new { City = "GitHub", State = "WWW" } } };
Debug.Assert("Smart from GitHub, WWW" == Smart.Format("{Name} from {Address.City}, {Address.State}", dict));`

Comment: Rather than adding more questions you should be modifying the original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027613/convert-string-to-object-in-c-sharp....

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make an object of anonymous type at runtime. Although anonymous types are, well, anonymous, they are *static* types, i.e. their members are known at compile time. Unless all keys and values of your dictionary are known at compile time (which defeats the purpose, really) you cannot make a static type from the dictionary.

The next closest thing would be to use a `dynamic` type with an `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
var tmp = (IDictionary<string,object>)obj;
foreach (var p in dict) {
    tmp[p.Key] = p.Value;
}
```

Now you can write

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", obj.key1, obj.key2);
```

This will compile and run, as long as `dict` cntains keys `key1` and `key2`.

Comment: Does not work: if obj is declared as ExpandoObject the compiler gives error message: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'. The same message appears at runtime if obj is declared as dynamic.

Comment: @Almis I forgot that you need to cast `ExpandoObject` to dictionary. See the edit.