# Accessed JArray values with invalid key value in different json

Tags: c#, json

I've this json:

```
{
     "status": true,
     "Text": "Example"
}
```

But sometimes this could change, so I need to check if the index Text is available in the response passed, code:

```
var container = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
var message = container["Text"];
```

the problem is that I get this exception on message (if the json doesn't contain the key `text`):

> {"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"Text\". Int32 array index expected."}

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript.

Comment: To be precise, you need to check if the property exists, and only then access it.

Comment: @Christoph yes I need to check if the property exists, you have linked a javascript question not c#

Comment: My bad. Then look at this posting. Cast to JObject and iterate over JObject.Children(). Does that work for you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652983/dynamic-jcontainer-json-net-iterate-over-properties-at-runtime

Comment: @Christoph I found the problem. The json returned (who cause the problem) contains multiple lines like this: `{"trace":{"details":{"[date]":"[29-02-2016 17:07:29.773750]","[level]":"[info]","[message]":"[System Done.]"},"context":[[{"ID":"John Dillinger"}]]}}{"trace":{"details":{"[date]":"[29-02-2016 17:07:29.773750]","[level]":"[info]","[message]":"[System Done.]"},"context":[[{"ID":"John Dillinger"}]]}}` infact I saw that if I place only one "trace" of the json the code work's fine, instead with the multiple line I got the error.

Comment: @Sandokan It appears the JSON you've posted is invalid. This could be the source of your problem.

Comment: @JosephWoodward it's not possible, I can parse it correctly. It's a simple array of json

Comment: Not sure if you found the problem but I had similar error on Azure and for me fix was to use https in my post url. I am not sure if it is related as I cant see what you do exactly in your code. you can find my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664576/set-jarray-values-with-invalid-key-value-version-int32-array-index-expected

Answer (score 1):

What version of NewtonSoft are you using?

The following results in `message` being null and no exception is thrown.

```
var res = @"{""status"": true }";

var container = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
var message = container["Text"];

// message = null
```

Update:

Following your response, even this doesn't throw the exception you're seeing:

```
var res = @"{}";

var container = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
var message = container["Text"];
```

Having updated my code to reflect yours with the same version I'm still not getting the exception you're seeing. This is what I'm doing:

```
var res = @"{""trace"":{""details"":{""[date]"":""[29-02-2016 17:07:29.773750]"",""[level]"":""[info]"",""[message]"":""[System Done.]""},""context"":[[{""ID"":""John Dillinger""}]]}}";

var container = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
var message = container["Text"];
```

The `message` variable is still null.

In light of this perhaps try create a simple console application with the above code and see if you get the same exception?

Comment: I know it, the code working. But as I said if the json returned is different against this `@"{""status"": true }";` I'll get the exception: `{"Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: \"Text\". Int32 array index expected."}` 'cause the key doesn't exists. It's clear now?

Comment: Can you update your question with code that causing the exception so I can try replicate it?

Comment: Is the same code, just pass another json that doesn't contain the `Text` key

Comment: Oh I found the problem, In the try catch I manage only the `WebException`m but if I replace with `Exception` I can't use some property of web exception-

Comment: What I don't get is why the object all of a sudden is a JArray. I would expect that the Json would have to have [ ] around it to be an array. The Json in the first code block clearly looks like an object to me that should not be deserialized into an object. @Sandokan, are you absolutely sure that in the failure cases you are receiving a Json object and not an array?

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm still not getting an exception. The `message` variable is simply set to null.

Comment: @Christoph yes I'm sure now I get this exception: `'System.ArgumentException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll` on this line: `var message = container["Text"];` and the code stop the execution

Comment: What version of Newtonsoft are you running?

Comment: @JosephWoodward is the 8.0.0.0

Comment: @Sandokan: Please capture an example of the Json PLAIN TEXT that is causing the exception.

Comment: this is the json: `{"trace":{"details":{"[date]":"[29-02-2016 17:07:29.773750]","[level]":"[info]","[message]":"[System Done.]"},"context":[[{"ID":"John Dillinger"}]]}}`

Comment: Just tried the exact json and updated to version 8 and still no exception. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JosephWoodward Please, check my last comment in the topic and also try multiple trace json line. I found the problem maybe.