# Set JArray values with invalid key value: "version". Int32 array index expected

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I created with offline sync option using azure mobile services. Everything worked fine at the beginning. I inserted several rows and I came back to my app after couple of days when I tried to make an insert into my table. I am getting the error message as

```
System.ArgumentException: Set JArray values with invalid key value: "version". Int32 array index expected.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.set_Item (System.Object key, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken value) [0x00028] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.GetJTokenFromResponse (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpResponse response) [0x00035] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<>c__DisplayClass14+<<InsertAsync>b__13>d__16.MoveNext () [0x000f7] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I tried to add the version property as below in my todoitem.cs

```
    [Version]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

or

```
    [TimeStamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

But neither cases helped me. I get the error only when I try to insert. reading data is just fine. Is it expecting me to set something. I thought that it is assigned automatically during a new row insert and used only to verify between row version of data between server and client.

UPDATE: what I changed was after it was working, I changed the schema permissions to "Authenticated users only" for each actions and also added an authentication with google and after that I was keep getting this error whatever I do. I cleaned table on local sqlite and azure but it didnt even help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally struggling almost entire 2 days I figure out the problem. I had to use https in my mobileApiUrl while creating MobileServiceClient. This was working fine before I didnt use any authentication on insert and update but once I add authentication with google and facebook, I started getting this error although read queries were still working. i dont know what is the reason behind it but changing from http to https worked like a charm.

```
  MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Url);
```

Comment: It's hard to say why, but you are correct.  Most of the auth settings require https, so I suspect that the token was not being transmitted properly due to the expectation of https and causing the failure.

Comment: @AdrianHall obviously. I wish that Azure was at least returning some proper error message instead of misleading one. I was so surprised to not to find any single entry about this error after googling for 2 days. Anyhow I hope this entry helps anyway might encounter same error.